# Ember Data's API call signature

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm a newbie to Ember Data and I've just switched from FIXTURE data to the RESTAdapter but I don't know enough about how to connect the model and the API's call signature. Specifically I'd like to be able to call an endpoint `GET /activities/[:user_id]/[:by_date]`. This would load an array of "Activity" objects but only those for a given date.

Router:

```
this.resource('activities', { path: '/activities' }, function() {
    this.route('by_date', {path: '/:user_id/:by_date'});
});
```

Route:

```
App.ActivitiesByDateRoute = Ember.Route.extend({  
    serialize: function(activity) {
      return {
        userId: 1,
        dateBy: "2013-07-01"
      };
    }     
});
```

First off I tried to hard code the values for `userId` and `dateBy` making the adjustments to the Route above. Sadly that did not work. I think I understand why -- although I don't have a quick way to fix this -- but more disturbing for me was that when I manually put in the parameters into the URL: `http://restful.service.com/api/activities/1/2013-07-01`. The results are quite surprising to me:

- Initially the debugging messages suggest a success:
  [image]
- This however, is not correct as no network requests are actually made
- If you reload the browser, it will now go out and get the Activities but to my surprise it also goes out to find the specified user. Hmmm. That's ok, the user 1 is pulled back successfully. 
  [image]
- The Activity, however, is just a `GET /activities` call which fails because this endpoint needs the user and date qualifier to work. Why weren't these included in the request?
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ember data supports "composite keys" (which is essentially what you are trying to do).  You'd probably need to build your own Ajax for that specific model and implement it in the model hook for that specific route.  You can always fetch the data and sideload it into ember-data if you'd like to have an ember data model.

Comment: When you say "side-load it into ember-data" I'm not sure what you mean. I am familiar with side-loading referenced ids but I think you're maybe referring to something slightly different?

Comment: I was at a training with Tom and Yehuda (the founders) and they were talking about how Ember Data was being built to solve the very cookie cutter solution of a model and an id.  That being said, Ember doesn't require Ember Data.  There are other ways of handling your models, ember model for example.  And sideloading, is the process of taking json of a model and pushing it into ember data/model without actually loading a model.  Then when you request a model by id which matches the id of the sideloaded data it will construct the model then without going back to the server.